# Android:Listview only display one result/ one line

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've problem to populate data from database to listview. Which is my db have more than 1 row, but in the listview only display 1 result which is the first data I save. Now we going to skip save function and straightly go to code for the adapter. For example I've one button and act as refresh button. On click of that button it will do the following line of code;

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View v){
              refreshAdapter();
          }
    });

    public void refreshAdapter(){
         SQLiteDatabase db=null;
         String path=DBPATH+DBNAME;

         db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
         Cursor resultset = db.query("Event_Log", null, null, null, null, null,   null);

        if(resultset.getCount()>0){
           resultset.moveToFirst();             
           List<String> arl = new ArrayList<String>();              
           while(resultset.isAfterLast()==false){

              arl.add(resultset.getString(6).toString() + "\n" +  resultset.getString(3).toString() 
                                + " " + resultset.getString(4).toString() 
                                + "@@" + resultset.getString(1).toString());                    
                        resultset.moveToNext();                         
                    }               
             Toast.makeText(refView.getContext(), "arl size " + arl.size() + " arl value " + arl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.personList);
             lView.setAdapter(new PersonAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arl));
    }
}
```

here is my adapter

```
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class PersonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> list;
    private TextView descHolder;
    private ImageView typeHolder; 

    public PersonAdapter(Context c, List<String> list){
        super(c, R.layout.person_adapter, list);
        this.context = c;
        this.list = list;                               
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup group){               
            if(convertview==null){
                LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertview = inf.inflate(R.layout.person_adapter, null);
                descHolder = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.personDescLbl);
                typeHolder = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.presonCategoryImage);
            }           

            String[]  textSplit = list.get(position).toString().split("@@");
            descHolder.setText(textSplit[0]);
            if(position%2==0){
                descHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#badce8"));
            }else{
                descHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
            }

            String category = textSplit[1];                     
            if(category.equals("Male")){
                typeHolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.maleicon);
            }else{
                typeHolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_icon);
            }                   
        return convertview;
    }
}
```

My person_adapter layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/personDescLbl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/personCategoryImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>          
</LinearLayout>
```

Onclick of the button I also put Toast function and display value/size of the arraylist, it toast the exact value like in the db, only in the adapter it display the first data I save. Please guide me.

Comment: Can you put a log in `getView()` to see how many times it's called?

Comment: I put the log and it being display so many times, more than total number of row in my db. what does this means?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your code has anymore issues, but here is a big one: in your getView, descHolder and typeHolder will only have the right value if convertView is null. Here is what your getView should look like (untested), using the ViewHolder pattern:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup group){               
        ViewHolder vh;

        if(convertview==null){
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertview = inf.inflate(R.layout.person_adapter, null);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.descHolder = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.personDescLbl);
            vh.typeHolder = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.presonCategoryImage);
            convertview.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder)convertview.getTag();
        }

        String[] textSplit = list.get(position).toString().split("@@");
        vh.descHolder.setText(textSplit[0]);
        if(position%2==0){
            vh.descHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#badce8"));
        }else{
            vh.descHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
        }

        String category = textSplit[1];                     
        if(category.equals("Male")){
            vh.typeHolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.maleicon);
        }else{
            vh.typeHolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_icon);
        }                   
    return convertview;
}
```

where ViewHolder is just an inner class of your adapter:

```
class ViewHolder {
    public TextView descHolder;
    public ImageView typeHolder;
}
```

I haven't checked your code for other issues, but this should give you a place to start.

Comment: this is the same like tutorial provide by http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html the only different is they create static class of viewholder. I already  tried creating viewholder class, but I get force close error, If I removed the inner class code is working but only display one result in the list view

Comment: sorry, i forgot to put convertview.setTag(vh);
that's why i got force close error. but the result still the same, only one display. Is it related to listview xml layout? Below is my listview layout define in xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView    
     android:id="@+id/eomLbl"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List of Person.."
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
   <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/personlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eomLbl"></ListView> 
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Try changing your listview's layout_height to fill_parent. You may also want to change the layout_height for the textview and imageview in your person_adapter to wrap_content. Does the list you insert into the adapter get populated correctly?

Comment: only list in first index being populated in the listview, and the size of the array list return the total number of row from db based on the toast.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your list size gets more than one and what the listvalues you got inside the view.

Comment: list size more than one, but i put log in the getview(int position, view v, viewgroup group,) method and print position value, the value always 0. I try the same thing on different adapter which is I use for my gridview, and the position print based on sequence 0,1,2,3,4.